# SQLite3 COUNT incorrect

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, ios, sqlite

Say i've got a table called Incidents, and a table called Devices.

Each device has a CI-code.

I want to create a tableView, with in the sections the names of the devices (CI), and each row to represent an incident.
To get the correct number of rows under each section, I use the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *lijstDevices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
const char *dbpath = [appDelegate.databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT DISTINCT CI FROM Devices"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            //  NSLog(@"SQLite ROW for filling in cell");
            NSString *addDev = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            [lijstDevices addObject:addDev];
         }
         sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    NSString *ciNaam = [lijstDevices objectAtIndex:section];

     NSString *querySQL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Incidents WHERE CI='%@'", ciNaam];
     const char *query_stmt2 = [querySQL2 UTF8String];

     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt2, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
         //NSLog(@"SQLite ok in rowforindexpath");
         if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
             //  NSLog(@"SQLite ROW for filling in cell");
             teller = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
         }
         else
         {
              NSLog(@"Not.. good...");
         }
         sqlite3_finalize(statement);
      }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

}

Here comes the problem: The sections are filled correctly. Some sections need 1 row, other sections need 2 rows. Whenever I run the program, each section which needs 1 row ends up with 0 rows, while each section with 2 rows needed end up with only 1 row.

Besides that, I had an error before which didn't clean the tables. Therefore, if I ran it twice, the database got doubled up on rows. In that case, each one which needed 1, has 2 rows. Each one which needed 2, had 4 rows. This is obviously not the case anymore but it might help understanding what's wrong.

Anyone having any idea???

Comment: try SELECT * COUNT() FROM Incidents WHERE CI='%@'

Comment: I guess you ment SELECT COUNT (*), @ViTo Brothers Apoyan, but it didn't work out neither :( It gets the correct number, only halved.. or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no error in this line. Apparently, the CI-code didn't get added in the table correctly. Sometimes it shows the CI-code correct (the ones I can see in the list), but the others just have (null) or 1 as code.

Answer (score 1):

u see this example and check it

```
-(void)ChekInDataBase{
    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {   
        NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT count(id) as countRow FROM password"];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",sqlStatement);

            if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                countRow = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0 )]intValue] ;
            }       
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

        if  (countRow > 0)
        {
            [yesBtnPressed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yes_tab_over.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [noBtnPressed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_tab.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [noBtnPressed setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
            [yesBtnPressed setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
        }
        else    
        {  
            [yesBtnPressed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yes_tab.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [noBtnPressed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_tab_over.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [noBtnPressed setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
            [yesBtnPressed setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }       
}
```

Comment: I changed the line to `@"SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CountRow FROM Incidents WHERE CI='%@'", ciNaam];`, but I'm afraid it has no effect :(

Comment: u check this query in sqllite...u will understnd where will create error